# Getting percentage of levels in a factor in R

Tags: r

I have a factor called all_factors. I want to get the percentages of the different levels in that factor.

For example, let's say all_factors has the levels: "a", "b", "c". So I would want something that would tell me 30% of the levels are "a", 20% are "b", and 50% are "c".

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please read [MCVE]. Can you edit your question and provide us some sample data and a sample of what you are looking for as output?

Comment: @ShawnMehan updated

Answer (score 1):

Try `table(all_factors)/sum(table(all_factors))`.

Comment: Is there a way for me to extract just the percentage from the table?